# Saving and loading std::chrono::time_point to file

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, fstream, c++-chrono

I am trying to simply save and reload the current time in a file. For example:

```
std::ifstream ifs(solar_system_cache_file,
        std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    return false;
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point cache_valid_time;
ifs >> cache_valid_time;

if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() < cache_valid_time) {
    std::cout << "Cache is VALID." << std::endl;
}
ifs.close();
return true;
```

and

```
std::ofstream ofs(solar_system_cache_file,
        std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

if (!ofs.is_open())
    return;

ofs << std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 12h;
ofs.close();
```

This sort of thing isn't complicated, but I've been looking around for hours and I cannot find relevant info. There are some example on how to cast using `duration_cast<long, std::milli>`, but `std::chrono` is extremely convoluted and hard to navigate (and digest).

In a nutshell, I believe I need to cast the current time to `long` (or some similar large type) and save that. When deserializing the time, I just have to cast it back to a `time_point`. It sounds easy enough, but I am unable to do so.

Finally, simply piping the time in `fstream` gives the usual `invalid operands to binary expression` error.

Any help is appreciated, or links to good tutorials/guides.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want the serialized format to be human readable?

Comment: No, it is in binary form. I posted my solution as an answer, feel free to take a jab at the problem of course :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want binary serialization, don't use formatted text routines to implement your serialization. :-]

A clock's `time_point` is just a wrapper around an arithmetic type that is the number of periods of some unit of time elapsed since the clock's epoch. All you really need to do is serialize that arithmetic value in its binary form:

**Saving**

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using clock_t = std::chrono::system_clock;

std::ofstream ofs{ solar_system_cache_file, std::ios::binary };
if (!ofs.is_open()) {
    return;
}

auto const cache_time = (clock_t::now() + 12h).time_since_epoch().count();
ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&cache_time), sizeof cache_time);
ofs.close();
```

**Loading**

```
std::ifstream ifs{ solar_system_cache_file, std::ios::binary };
if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    return false;
}

clock_t::rep file_time_rep;
if (!ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&file_time_rep), sizeof file_time_rep)) {
    return false;
}
ifs.close();

clock_t::time_point const cache_valid_time{ clock_t::duration{ file_time_rep } };
std::time_t const file_time{ clock_t::to_time_t(cache_valid_time) };
std::cout << std::ctime(&file_time);
```

Note that passing `openmode::in` to an input stream and `openmode::out` to an output stream is redundant.

Also, importantly, note that binary serialization is not portable:

1. The type of `std::chrono::system_clock::rep` is implementation-defined — the only requirement is that it's a signed arithmetic type — and so can change from one compiler/stdlib/build config to the next.
2. Even if you controlled the representation type via `std::chrono::duration_cast`, the endianness of integral types and representation of floating-point types as a whole are architecture-specific.

Consequently, you can only rely on deserializing data with code that was built with the same architecture/compiler/stdlib/config as the serialization code.

Comment: In addition, the epoch may change even from run to run (for `system_clock` it doesn't in practice, but there's no guarantee).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I am quite confused about `rep`, what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: @Socapex : `rep` is the type used to hold the number of time units elapsed since epoch. On my system `system_clock::period` is `std::nano` and `system_clock::rep` is `long long`, thus the value serialized is a `long long` containing the number of nanoseconds elapsed since epoch.

Comment: @T.C.:  Since `system_clock` is required to have a converting relationship with `time_t`, then if the epoch changed from run to run, either the epoch of `time_t` would also have to change from run to run in the exact same way, or the functions that converts between `system_clock` to/from `time_t` would have to track this epoch change in one or both sides.  In practice, every `system_clock` (and every `time_t`) measure Unix Time:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you so much for taking the time to explain all of this, and a great answer. Somehow I forgot about casting to char (haven't done c++ serialization in while). Have a great day!

Comment: How do i compare the time which I've saved then loaded to the current time of the system? How do i get the days between them?

Comment: @PackOf20 : [`system_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) and [`operator -`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2)

Comment: don't use 'clock_t' name, at least not for MSVC 2022 there's 'typedef long clock_t' inside 'time.h'

Answer (score 1):

Ok well after some more fiddling around I finally got it.

The answer is `std::time_t`, and it's friends `std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t` and `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t`.

So to save, all you have to do is convert `::now()` to `time_t` and pipe that in your file. To load, do the inverse using `from_time_t`.

**Saving**

```
std::ofstream ofs(solar_system_cache_file,
        std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

if (!ofs.is_open())
    return;

auto cache_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 12h;
ofs << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(cache_time);
ofs.close();
```

**Loading**

```
std::ifstream ifs(solar_system_cache_file,
        std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    return false;
}

std::time_t file_time;
ifs >> file_time;
std::cout << std::ctime(&file_time);

auto cache_valid_time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(file_time);
ifs.close();
```

Quite simple after all, cheers!

Comment: This is ok if you are satisfied with the precision of `time_t` (in text form), which is typically seconds.  ildjarn's answer is precise to whatever units your `system_clock` measures to (nanoseconds in your case), and uses a more compact binary form.